# Create an Eclipse Template for Custom Indentation for Maps

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-templates

Is there a way to create a custom indentation for an object type in Eclipse?

I store unit tests in groovy beans. As different tests contain different levels of complexity I want to force a certain format such at below:

```
overrideExampleTest(OverrideTestCaseData,
    name        : 'overrideExampleTest',
    description : 'ExampleFormatting for StackOverflow',
    overrideTestCaseData : [
                            field1     : 'value1',
                            field20    : 'value20',
                            nestedList : [
                                            [                                               [
                                                 type       : 'SSL',
                                                 quantity  : 1,
                                                 termYears : 1,
                                            ]
                            ]]
)
```

I like the clean look and easy readability. If I use the default Correct Indentation I see the following:

```
overrideExampleTest(OverrideTestCaseData,
name        : 'overrideExampleTest',
description : 'ExampleFormatting for StackOverflow',
overrideTestCaseData : [
       field1     : 'value1',
       field20    : 'value20',
       nestedList : [
              [                                                                                                                                                                                              [
                           type       : 'SSL',
                           quantity  : 1,
                           termYears : 1
                     ]
              ]]
       )
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: no, also eat some poop